# Integrar Mercadopago a Django

Tags: python, django

Hola quiero integrar Mercadopago a mi proyecto de Django, tengo un gran problema, estoy trancado en el primer paso. SOY SUPER NOVATO aclaro.
Me pide que cree una preferencia y mi duda es si tengo q crear un script o donde tengo q crear esa preferencia y tambien que datos van en la preferncia.
Muchisimas gracias desde ya
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]